# PHP Query to Insert Variables into MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql

The query below is not inserting the variables into MySQL.  I know that the function `valid_email2` works because I put a non-email address into  `$inviteeemail` and it redirected per the code below.

I know that I have the right MySQL connection string.

Any idea why nothing is being put into MySQL?

```
$invitorname = $_POST['invitorname'];
$inviteename = $_POST['inviteename'];
$inviteeemail = $_POST['inviteeemail'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$subcheck = (isset($_POST['subcheckinvite'])) ? 1 : 0;

if ( ! valid_email2($inviteeemail))
{
    session_write_close();
    header("Location:http://www...com/.../file.php");
    exit;   
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO invites VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '$inviteeemail', '$invitorname', '$inviteename', NULL, '$subcheckinvite', NULL)");
}
```

Comment: Please `echo mysql_error();` after your query and tell us the output to help us help you :)

Comment: Does the fields that you insert NULL for, can be null?

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski: thanks, I can't use NULL for the last field.  I switched it and it works.

Comment: Then that is the answer? :) I should move my comment

Comment: @Nikola, yes, move it and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Please don't leave your code as-is now that you've fixed the immediate error. There are much deeper problems to resolve with what you've written.

Comment: @Dan, yeah, I plan on fixing MySQL injection issues later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the fields that you insert NULL for, can be null?

Comment: my last field cannot be NULL.  I changed it and now it works.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your query you have `$subcheckinvite` but you're setting it as `$subcheck` at the beginning of your script.  Maybe that's it.

Comment: Thanks... I was really hoping that was it.  But it still doesn't work with the correct variable.

Answer (score -1):

Check the return value of `mysql_query`. If it is false, then the query was not valid, and you can print `mysql_error()` to see the error message.

It's not unlikely that this stems from the fact that you're not escaping any of the user input. Aside from allowing someone to completely change your query by carefully crafting the form inputs, your query will simply fail if any of the fields contain a single quote mark.

Besides fixing your error, you should consider improving the quality of your code.

- You use variables that don't exist (`$checksubinvite`)
- You insert NULLs into columns rather than simply specifying which columns you do want to insert into
- You do not validate all of the inputs
- You have single quotes around what are likely numeric columns
- You have enormous amounts of whitespace and inconsistent indentation

...etc.